# React Class to Function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm on the step of converting one of my Class components to a functional one, however, I'm thinking of better way of handling state from the functional version.

Currently, here is my Class component state:

```
this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {},
    };
```

On functional component version ,Currently I would have to break those states into three different states using UseState:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setpassword] = useState("");
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

is there a way to combine these states in 1 state that is an object by default like this:

```
const [states,setStates] = useState({
    email:"",
    password:"",
    errors:{}
});
```

Reason why is because I have this kind of code from my class components, and I dont think this will work if I opted for the first Functional comp. setup:

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. But you have to modify your setState Function like this

```
     handleChange = (event) => {
        setStates({ ...states , [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
     };
```

you have to do this on every setState call wherever you do .

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve that using a custom hook:

```js
const useLegacyState = initialState => {
  return useReducer((prevState, newState) => {
    return typeof newState === 'function'
    ? { ...prevState, ...newState(prevState) }
    : { ...prevState, ...newState };
  }, initialState);
};
```

And usage:

```js
const [states, setStates] = useLegacyState({
  email: '',
  password: '',
  errors: {}
});

const handleChange = event => {
  setStates({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the structure of the state variable is totally up to you.

Note, however, that this means that every time you call `setStates` you'll need to provide the entire structure.

You can use something like `Object.assign` to "update" existing state like this:

```
setStates(Object.assign({}, states, {a: 'b'}));
```

This would add the `a` key with a `b` value to the state, without changing previous ones.

Comment: what would the difference of this method with the spread operator? like ({...states,{a:'b'})

Comment: That's basically the same, it was just an example.